# phone number from device returns 0

Tags: java, android, contacts, android-contacts

i'm kinda new to android developing, and i'm completely stuck now! 
so i'm hoping that you will help me!

So - i'm trying to get the phone number and email address from a contact, in a contact picker.
but when i'm displaying the output, it says it is 0 and null. 
what am I doing wrong? 
here's the code!

```
if (view == btnPhonebook2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }

  public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT):
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // String id = null;
            // FIRST TRY

              Uri contactData = data.getData(); Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null); 
              if(c.moveToFirst()) { 
                  String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME)); 
                  int number = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.PRIMARY_PHONE_ID));
                  String email = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ID));


              //+" : c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER));
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you selected : "+name+"\n With the telephone number :"+number+"\n And the email :"+email,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which){
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "60158096"));
                              startActivity(intent);
                            break;

                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                              email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"emailExample@gmail.com"});          
                              email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                              email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
                              email.setType("message/rfc822");
                              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("How will you contact: "+name).setPositiveButton("Call", dialogClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton("Email", dialogClickListener).show();
```

when I display the String name - it comes out fine!?

Comment: Share some more code like what is getData();

Comment: seems like it is a bild in function to retrive data from intent
"Retrieve data this intent is operating on.  This URI specifies the name of the data; often it uses the content: scheme, specifying data in a content provider.  Other schemes may be handled by specific activities, such as http: by the web browser."

Comment: but I can share some more, though i'm pretty sure, that my error is in the posted section.

Comment: I don't think it's the cause, but I don't see where this condition block ends, `if(c.moveToFirst()) {`

Comment: oh yeah - It end after a bunch of commented out code, that I have underneath this - so it is there. don't you worry ;-)

Comment: I would add an image of the output, but my rep isn't high enough :-D

Comment: People.PRIMARY_PHONE_ID will give you id not PhoneNumber. And The class  Contacts.People is deprecated from api 5. See link in the answer.